# All possible team rosters algorithm? Similar to knapsack maybe?

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I have been working on a hobby project for a while that involves finding all possible team rosters given the constraints of a salary cap and player positions while trying to N `teams` with the maximum projection. This is specifically for fantasy football, but the problem can be more generalized to a maximization problem. I can't find a more efficient solution than using nested for loops. I am using python dictionaries to track specific player data by position where `qbs[playerName] = {Salary: X, Projection: Y}` and `rbs[playerName] = {Salary: X, Projection: Y}`, etc.

The constraints are as follows:

- 1 quarterback (qb)
- 2 running backs (rb1, rb2)
- 3 wide receivers (wr1,
  wr2, wr3)
- 1 tight end (te)
- 1 defense (dst)
- 1 flex player (can be a
  running back, a tight end, or a wide receiver)
- total salary has to be
  <= N

a general form of my algorithm follows:

```
def optimize(teams):
    for qb in qbs:
        iter_rb = itertools.combinations(rbs,2)
        for rb1, rb2 in iter_rb:
            iter_wr = itertools.combinations(wrs,3)
            for wr1, wr2, wr3 in iter_wr:
                for te in tes:
                    for dst in dsts:
                        baseSalary = qb['Salary'] + rb1['Salary'] + rb2['Salary'] + wr1['Salary'] + wr2['Salary'] + wr3['Salary'] + te['Salary'] + dst['Salary']
                        baseProjection = qb['Projection'] + rb1['Projection'] + rb2['Projection'] + wr1['Projection'] + wr2['Projection'] + wr3['Projection'] + te['Projection'] + dst['Projection']
                        if baseSalary <= maxSalary:
                            for rb3 in rbs:
                                salary = baseSalary + rb3['Salary']
                                if salary <= maxSalary:
                                    projection = baseProjection + rb3['Projection']
                                    if projection > teams[-1].projection:
                                        insertTeamAndReorderList()
                            for wr4 in wrs:
                                salary = baseSalary + wr4['Salary']
                                if salary <= maxSalary:
                                    projection = baseProjection + wr4['Projection']
                                    if projection > teams[-1].projection:
                                        insertTeamAndReorderList()
                            for te2 in tes:
                                salary = baseSalary + te2['Salary']
                                if salary <= maxSalary:
                                    projection = baseProjection + te2['Projection']
                                    if projection > teams[-1].projection:
                                        insertTeamAndReorderList()
    return teams
```

I feel like there is a more optimal solution, but I simply cannot figure out any more optimizations? Even when cutting `wrs` and `rbs` with low projections, this still takes a few hours to run.

Any ideas of where to look or confirmation that there isn't a more efficient solution would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: For clarification, I loop through the wrs, tes, and rbs again inside of the dst loop to search for the flex player. This reduces the search space greatly instead of having a list of all flex eligible players.

Comment: You want only the best solution (best projection) or all of them? I created a small MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) model and to find the best one takes zero seconds,

Comment: that's actually awesome and I'd be interested in seeing it. But I'm looking for the N best lineups, so not just 1 but all from 1 to N

Answer (score 4):

OK, as requested, here is my MIP model to find the best team.

[image]

Note that `minpos` and `maxpos` states how many players we want for each position. For `qb` we have `1 <= y(qb) <= 1`, but for `rb`: `2 <= y(rb) <= 3`, etc. The set `plpos` indicates at which position a player can play.

Now to find additional solutions, we can use some tools that some state-of-the-art solvers have (e.g. Cplex has a solution pool technology), or we can implement the following algorithm:

1. Solve model
2. If enough solutions: STOP
3. Add a constraint (`cut`) to the model that forbids the current solution
4. Go to step 1

How does this cut look like. Let `j` be set of players selected in the solution, i.e. with `x*(j)=1`. (There should be 9 of them). Then the cut can look like: `sum_j x(j) <= 8`. After each round in the algorithm we add a new cut (so the problem becomes larger and larger). Each iteration of the above algorithm gives you a new, unique, best solution.

A set of solutions can look like:

[image]

Comment: I'll definitely have to look into this! Thanks for sharing! If I make any kind of progress, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a [mathematical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) or [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) problem.  There are many libraries available to help you solve these types of problems efficiently (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optimization_software) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming#Constraint_programming_libraries_for_imperative_programming_languages), respectively).